# Fetch Uploaded File on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Am trying to upload an excel sheet in MVC 3.0 using cshtml. In my view, I have two buttons in my page, for each button a different action result. I have implemented the handling of two buttons in my page. However, when i click on the upload button, no files are there when Request.Files is given. Should i add a parameter in the ActionResult of Upload button click?
below is my code for

```
[HttpPost]
[MultiButton(MatchFormKey = "Upload", MatchFormValue = "Upload")]
public ActionResult UploadFile()
{
    TMReportViewModel UploadModel = new TMReportViewModel();
    foreach (string file in Request.Files) 
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase hpf = Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (hpf.ContentLength == 0) 
            continue;

        string savedFileName = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
              
        hpf.SaveAs(savedFileName); 
     }
     return View(UploadModel);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was currently working on this using ASP.NET MVC 4.0.

The solution is in HTML which is there:

You have to write

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadImage", "Image", FormMethod.Post,
                        new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

so that your controller knows that you are passing the image in *Request.File*.

For *more information*, look at *[Uploading and returning files in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/442515/Uploading-and-returning-files-in-ASP-NET-MVC)*.

And for ASP.NET MVC 3.0, look at *[How to upload image using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://forums.asp.net/t/1673787.aspx)*.